# Polynomial regression model to predict values for a variable with 500 rows

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression, polynomial-approximations, predictive

There are around `500` values `planned` and on the basis of this I have to predict new values `actual`.

Kindly help me with the coding, here I'm showing what I am doing manually:

```
predict(poly_reg, data.frame(planned= 48.80000,
                             Level2 = 48.80000^2,
                             Level3 = 48.80000^3))

lin_reg = lm(formula = actual ~ ., data = dataset)
summary(lin_reg)
# Fitting Polynomial Regression to the dataset
dataset$Level2 = dataset$planned^2
dataset$Level3 = dataset$planned^3
dataset$Level4 = dataset$Planned_FTM^0.25000
poly_reg = lm(formula = actual~ ., data = dataset)
# Visualising the Linear Regression results
# install.packages('ggplot2')
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = dataset$planned, y = dataset$actual), colour = 'red') + geom_line(aes(x = dataset$planned, y = predict(lin_reg, newdata = dataset)), colour = 'blue') + ggtitle('Truth or Bluff (Linear Regression)') + xlab('planned') + ylab('actual')

# Predicting a new result with Linear Regression
predict(lin_reg, data.frame(planned= 48.80000))
# Predicting a new result with Polynomial Regression
predict(poly_reg, data.frame(planned= 48.80000, Level2 = 48.80000^2, Level3 = 48.80000^3))
```

Comment: Something is not right, you should not have a square and a cube of your variable in the data, these terms should only be present in the model.

Comment: okay can you tell me how to do predictions for around 500 values

Comment: Its okay to create square or cube. This is called transformation. But, I am not sure what is 48.8 doing there. I suspect you are trying to forecast 501th value using 500 data point. Is this right? You don't need LM for this. Look at ARIMA or other forecasting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `poly` on `planned` to whatever order polynomial you're using (I used 4):

```
# Fitting Linear Regression to the dataset
lin_reg = lm(formula = actual ~ planned, data = dataset)

# Fitting Polynomial Regression to the dataset
poly_reg = lm(formula = actual ~ poly(planned, 4), data = dataset)

# Predicting a new result with Linear Regression
predict(lin_reg)

# Predicting a new result with Polynomial Regression
predict(poly_reg)
```